# Convert string to a tuple

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

'|Action and Adventure|Drama|Science-Fiction|Fantasy|'

How can I convert it to a tuple or a list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> s = '|Action and Adventure|Drama|Science-Fiction|Fantasy|'
>>> 
>>> [item for item in s.split('|') if item.strip()]
['Action and Adventure', 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Fantasy']
>>>
```

If you'd rather have a tuple then:

```
>>> tuple(item for item in s.split('|') if item.strip())
('Action and Adventure', 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Fantasy')
>>>
```

Comment: Also note that you should (probably) not use tuples in your case because you want multiple single component items, not one item with variable number of components.

Comment: @Alin: Didn't understand that. Care to explain?

Comment: I wanted to point out that it is not semantically correct to use tuples when you actually need lists.

Comment: Not semantically correct? Not sure why you say that, for two reasons (1) The OP specifically asked for a tuple _or_ a list. (2) unless you are planning to modify the sequence later, a tuple would do just as fine as a list.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru Tuples are just ordered lists of elements - they _are_ lists. If there's no need to use any of `list`'s methods, then `tuple` is a fine, concise choice of data storage.

Comment: A tuple(it doesn't matter how a programming language implements it) is an n-pair. When you say pair you know that the elements are connected and not independent. By analogy the components of a tuple (I don't name them items because they're not items) need to have a logical connection. On the other hand a list is just some items, you can add or remove and you will have the same object, but with more or less items. Example: (x1,x2) is a point in 2D, but (x1,x2,x3) - the same tuple with one element added - represents a point in 3D; [2,3,5] is a list of prime numbers, just like [2,3,5,7] and so on

Comment: `By analogy the components of a tuple (I don't name them items because they're not items) need to have a logical connection`: I beg to differ. To quote wikipedia: `In mathematics and _computer science_, a tuple is an ordered list of elements.`. That definition doesn't require the components to have a logical connection.

Comment: By being ordered they have a connection.

Comment: Following that logic lists should be fine since lists are also defined to be ordered: `In computer science, a list or sequence is an abstract data structure that implements an ordered collection of values`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(computing)

Comment: Alin Purcaru's argument is the one supported by Guido.  Tuples are like records.  Lists are sequences of objects of the same type.

Comment: I thought that seeing the difference between tuples and lists was common sense and I did not expect to generate such a comment **list** :).

Comment: What, you don't mean a tuple of comments? ;) Seriously, yes, I see your point. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: BTW, I would argue that in this case, `if item` is clearer and more concise than `if item.strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> s = '|Action and Adventure|Drama|Science-Fiction|Fantasy|'
>>> s.split('|')
['', 'Action and Adventure', 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Fantasy', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just split your string at the `|` character you use:

```
myStr.split('|')
```

If you also want all zero-length element removed (like the ones from the ends) you:

```
def myFilter(el): return len(el) > 0
filter(myFilter, myStr.split('|'))
```

Comment: Thanks won't work here ;-), Set this answer as your accepted answer" If so :)

Comment: `[ x for x in myStr.split('|') if len(x) > 0 ]` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

**Strip**
'string'.strip('|')

```
   >>> heading = '|Action and Adventure|Drama|Science-Fiction|Fantasy|'
   >>> tuple(heading.strip('|').split('|'))
   ('Action and Adventure', 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Fantasy')
```

**Slice**
'string'[1:-1]

```
   >>> heading = '|Action and Adventure|Drama|Science-Fiction|Fantasy|'
   >>> tuple(heading[1:-1].split('|'))
   ('Action and Adventure', 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Fantasy')
```

For **List** remove the *tuple()* call.

Answer (score 1):

`strip()` gets rid of the leading and trailing chars, `split()` divvies up the remainder:

```
>>> s.strip('|').split('|')
['Action and Adventure', 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Fantasy']
```

Answer (score 0):

### List

```
seq = '|Action and Adventure|Drama|Science-Fiction|Fantasy|'.split('|')
```

### Tuple

```
seq = tuple(seq)
```

If you want to strip empty items, pass the output through `filter(None, seq)`. If you assume outer `|` always, just slice with `seq[1:-1]`.